# How to sort dates in a column in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, rowsorter

I have the following jtable [jtable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUcvh.png) I get the information from a database and everything is saved as string in the table, I just want to sort the second column "Fecha de recepcion" which has dates in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`, I used a row classifier but it takes the dates as strings.

I made a `TableCellRenderer` for just that column and applied the following properties

```
Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer( new Render());
Table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

but it still sorts it as string.

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me on what I'm doing wrong

This is my class that implements `TableCellRenderer`

```
public class Render implements TableCellRenderer{
     private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(value.toString(),formatter);
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                date, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to look at [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and supply a custom comparator.  But since your data seems to be `String` based (`LocalDate.parse(value.toString(),formatter);`) you should probably look there first and make sure you data (in the table) is actually a `LocalDate`.  Also `DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();` is wasteful, you should just extend from `DefaultTableCellRenderer` directly

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing here is the data, what's in the `TableModel`, as this is what the table will use to sort by.

Based on `LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(value.toString(),formatter);` it would appear that your data is `String` based, which will be the cause of you core problem.

Instead, you data should be using `LocalDate`.  `LocalDate` is comparable by default, so you don't need any "special" comparators or additional support, it will "just work" out of the box, for example, unsorted, descending, ascending...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            long minDay = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).toEpochDay();
            long maxDay = LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31).toEpochDay();
            List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>(100);
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                long randomDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(minDay, maxDay);
                dates.add(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay));
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(new ExampleTabelModel(dates));
            table.setDefaultRenderer(LocalDate.class, new DateCellRenderer());
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }
    }

    public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
                value = ((LocalDate) value).format(formatter);
            }
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }

    public class ExampleTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private List<LocalDate> dates;

        public ExampleTabelModel(List<LocalDate> dates) {
            this.dates = dates;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: return "Rows";
                case 1: return "Dates";
            }            
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dates.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 1:
                    return LocalDate.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return rowIndex;
                case 1:
                    return dates.get(rowIndex);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```